# remove array item when user disconnects from node.js server

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, websocket

im trying to learn nodeJs by building a small game of who can push the button first,

When a user joins there pushed into array called "room", that holds their username and score, this is then broadcasted to all connected clients so let them know who's in the room

```
room.push({userName:userName,score:0});

var userName_json = JSON.stringify({ type:'userName', data: userName });
broadcastMessage(userName_json);
```

broadcasting them adds an html element to the page

```
      connection.onmessage = function (message) {

      if (json.type === 'userName') {
      addUser(json.data);

    }

  function addMessage(userName) {
    $('#' + userName).addClass('green');
    console.log(userName + 'hits first');
  }
```

When a user disconnects from the node server they need to be removed from this room

```
 connection.on('close', function(connection) {

    if (userName !== false) {
      console.log('user name is not false lets splice');
      console.log((new Date()) + " Peer "
          + connection.remoteAddress + " disconnected.");

      clients.splice(index, 1);
      room.splice(index, 1);

      var userName_json = JSON.stringify({ type:'retire', data: userName });
      broadcastMessage(userName_json);

    } else {
      console.log('cant do anything userName is false');
    }
  });
```

which removes the users html element

```
    connection.onmessage = function (message) {

else if (json.type === 'retire') {
      console.log(json);
      retireUser(json.data);
    }

function retireUser(userName) {
    $('#' + userName).remove();
    console.log(userName + ' cant handle the pressure');
  }
```

Now this works fine if a user joins the room then leaves, if a user joins a room with someone already in, or a user joins after them then they try to leave the user is not always removed from the room array, or the person who is still connected has their html element removed from there page.

Any ideas on whats wrong??

full gist https://gist.github.com/jkirkby91/9f93ed2cf4e1aa7870e7

Comment: I believe there is some code missing, where do You declare the index variable in your connection close function?  and userName?

Comment: i've not missed any code from that function pasting here maybe it is what im missing ive updated the question with a gist of server.js

https://gist.github.com/jkirkby91/9f93ed2cf4e1aa7870e7

Comment: You've got only two `var` in presented code and lots of variables. Where do you declare them?

Comment: which variables? all the code is in the gist

Answer (score 2):

I use map/object to store key/val data instead of array.

```
next_uid = 0;
users = {};

wsserver.on('connection', function (conn) {
        conn.user_id = ++new_uid; // you can store user-ID here
        users[conn.user_id] = { /* any user data you want */ }
        conn.on('message', function (message) {
                 console.log('message form ' + conn.user_id);
        });

        conn.on('close', function (code, reason) {
                console.log(conn.user_id + ' disconnected');
                delete users[conn.user_id];
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I spotted is [here](https://gist.github.com/jkirkby91/9f93ed2cf4e1aa7870e7#file-server-js-L66); you can't assume that the index will stay the same. If a different connection with a smaller index is removed, all indexes above shift by -1. You have to find out the index [when you remove](https://gist.github.com/jkirkby91/9f93ed2cf4e1aa7870e7#file-server-js-L123):

```
  var index = clients.indexOf(connection);
  clients.splice(index, 1);
  room.splice(index, 1);
```

I also think it's not a good idea to use usernames as html ids, especially if they can contain spaces. Instead, you should assign a unique number as an id to each user.